# Why are there holes in my exported meshes?

Tags: modeling, export, unreal-engine

Hello Blender Community!

I am currently learning with Blender 2.71 and use Unreal Engine 4.

I started to create a Knife, but I always have problems exporting it.
I tried to recalculate normals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> but it still cut off.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: BLender]
[image: Unreal Engine]

[image: Blender]

[image: Exporting Options]

Comment: the shortcut to recalculate normals is Ctrl N, not Ctrl A.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing the topology? You might have ngons or something.

Comment: @gandalf3 i'm sorry but what do you mean with topology and ngons? top ortho?

Comment: In edit mode, so that you can see the edges and faces

Comment: @gandalf3 ok included it

Comment: You've got ngons, one the faces of your knife, removing them should fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot be certain of what is wrong without a .blend. my best guess is that your issue is caused by **NGons**. NGons are faces with more the four edges.

to remove them, select the faces that are Ngons

(<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>>*Select Faces by Sides*>set number of vertices to grater that 4 and type to *greater than*)

then delete them useing <kbd>X</kbd>>*Only Faces*. then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

The faces on the sides of the knife seem to be [N-gons](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh).

Try triangulating the mesh before exporting it:

1. In edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select everything (<kbd>A</kbd>) or just the ngons by pressing *3D view > Header > Select > Faces by sides*, then setting the *type* to *greater than* in the redo panel (<kbd>F6</kbd>):

   [image]
2. Triangulate the faces by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>:

   [image]

If you want more control over the triangulation, you might try using the [*triangulate modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Triangulate).

Answer (score 0):

Tris and Quads are fine but N-gons create this issue in unity when it can't decide how to tesellate.

Removing n-gons did the job for me

To remove n-gons just add an extra edge to divide them into quads and tris for the faces where you are facing the problem; if you cant afford more UVs and tris. Otherwise go with the processes as mentioned above